# Filtering linq collection (parent) based on another collection (child)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am filtering a collection based on a child collection.

My models are as follows:

First

```
    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public double Stock { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}
```

and second

```
    public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool isSelected { get; set; }
    }
```

and a ViewModel for passing it to my view

```
public class ProductsVM
{
    public IList<Item> items { get; set; }
    public IList<Category> categories { get; set; }

}
```

and my action method where I get the list of categories (check boxes in view).

The following code runs successfully where I remove unselected categories.

```
    productsVm.categories.RemoveAll(x => x.isSelected == false);
```

Now I want items with only selected categories.

I have tried

```
    List<Item> items = db.Items.ToList();
    List<Item> filter = items.Where(x => !categories.Any( y=> y.Id == x.Category.Id)).ToList();
```

and

```
   var model = (from it in db.Items
                join ct in productsVm.categories
                on it.Category.Id equals ct.Id
                select it).ToList();
```

and

```
            List<Item> items = db.Items.ToList();
            List<Item> filter = items.RemoveAll(x => productsVm.categories.Contains(x.Category.Id));
```

Comment: Have you tried items.Where(i => i.Category.isSelected)?

Comment: Thats another problem, i view is not returning my ViewModel, it only returns the Categories in productsVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only the categories ids:

```
var ids=productsVm.categories.Select(c=>c.Id);//.Distinct();
//Using the ids collection now you can filter the item like and IN in sql
var query=db.Items.Where(i=>ids.Contains(i.Category.Id));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @octavioccl. Finally it worked. Thanks again. :)